# Chunk importer Excel file in Laravel

Tags: excel, laravel, chunks, maatwebsite-excel, laravel-excel

I am using maatwebsite/excel package and I want to upload files that contain data of users. Then, I sorted the file by last name, and finally, I tried to chunk the file into files. Each file includes ten users, I made all correctly, but the file results are empty.

**Controller**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $file = $request->file('excel_file');
    $data = Excel::toArray([], $file)[0];

    // Remove metadata row
    array_shift($data);

    // Sort by the "LASTNAME" column
    usort($data, function ($a, $b) {
        return strnatcmp($a[2], $b[2]);
    });

    // Chunk the data into files of 10 users
    $chunks = array_chunk($data, 10);
    foreach ($chunks as $index => $chunk) {
        $filename = 'students_'.($index + 1).'.xlsx';

        dd(collect($chunk)); //THIS SHOWING ME DATA 
        Excel::store(collect($chunk), $filename, 'public');
    }
    
    return "DONE";
}
```

The result is good, but the files are empty.